# PHP Reading mp3 ID3 tags

Tags: php, mp3, pecl, id3

I am just getting started using ID3, and I had a simple script that gets the mp3 files, then gets the ID3 tags with `id3_get_tag("/path/to/file/file.mp3", ID3_BEST)` It works on most of the mp3 files I tried it with, but they didn't have any album artwork info. I then tried it with an mp3 that was about 18.3 mb and it had the album artwork and everything with it. But whenever I try to read the tags, I get this error `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 543296730 bytes)` It was trying to allocate about 500mb for some reason. If anybody could help with this it would be great! Thanks

Comment: If it's available to you, consider using ffinfo, part of FFmpeg.  It can handle more than just ID3 data, and almost any file type.

Comment: Do you have a link to the package/extension?

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/  It is available as a PHP extension, but I recommend just using `exec()`.